# Iterating through dictionary and numpy array simultaneously

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, numpy

Is there a slick way of iterating through a dictionary of objects, calling a member function of each object and assigning the value to a numpy array.  I have the following member function code:

```
    # Preallocate for Number of Objects in the dictionary
    newTable = numpy.zeros( self.numObj );

    for item, nt in zip( self.dictTable.values(), newTable ):
        dt = item.CalculateDutyCycle() * 100.0


    return newTable
```

This doesn't run because my assignment to the numpy array is not done correctly.  I can do it correctly using nditer, but was not sure how to combine that iterator with the dictionary table iteration.  I was avoiding the traditional 'counter' increment to access the array is there is a more elegant 'pythonic' solution.

Comment: The Pythonic way to avoiding explicit counters is `enumerate`. But the order of enumeration of a dictionaries items is indeterminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't seen any advantage to using `numpy` here, since you are iterating over a regular Python list (values()).  I'd just do a list comprehension, and convert it into an array later.  Also your array is 1d.  `numpy` shines when working with multidimensional objects (as opposed to simple lists).

```
list_answer = [item.CalculateDutyCycle() * 100.0 for item in self.dictTable.values()]
newTable = np.array(list_answer)
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to explicitly increment a counter if you use `enumerate`. You could do something like:

```
newTable = numpy.zeros( self.numObj )
for k, item in enumerate(self.dictTable.values()):
    newTable[k] = item.CalculateDutyCycle() * 100.0
```